# add_margin of reshape2 package

Tags: r, reshape2

In R, can anyone describe how "add_margin "of "reshape2" package works?
I have gone through the documentation of reshape2 package from cranR website.
But I could not understand it. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert and can only make a guess about the function. You can use it to rapidly combine all factor or group levels together:

```
# data
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=1:10)

# you may want to plot a boxplot
plot(b ~ a, df)

# add_margins
df1 <- add_margins(df, "a")
plot(b ~ a, df1)
```

[image]

But this is only one application. There should be more usefull stuff.